# IE9 CSS float:right Bug?

Tags: css, html, internet-explorer-9

Here are my styles:

Parent container:

```
div.musicContainer {
        width:820px;
        height:54px;
        margin-bottom:20px;
}
```

Child containers:

```
div.hardcorePlayer {
    width:400px;
    float:left;
    border:none;
    background-color:#996600;
}

div.feedbackPlayer {
    width:340px;
    float:right;
    border:none;
    background-color:#996600;
}
```

The issue is: i installed IE9 yesterday and while IE8 was displaying fine well now the *feedbackPlayer div* is not lined up to the right boundary any longer. it displays fine in other browsers as before.

is this a IE9 bug?

IE9 image:

[image: IE9 image]

other browser image:

[image: else]

thank you very much for your thoughts on this.

website url: [www.guygar.com/guygar.html](http://www.guygar.com/guygar.html)

NOTE: **here is the [new CSS](http://www.guygar.com/css/siteCssTemp.css) with the reset data.** Have i done something wrong?

Comment: FYI, your flash objects aren't showing up at all in IE.

Comment: Hi Thomas, I think it could be the way your IE is setup. The flash objects are working fine on my end.

Comment: Why do you wrap virtually every element in a single div? The way you use cursor: seems sub-optimal as well.

Comment: @phant0m: i am new to this. please explain your point further so i could understand the issue. thanks.

Comment: For instance, you have (virtually?) all images wrapped in a `<div>`. They don't seem to be necessary. You can use CSS to position (etc) images just as well as divs. There is no need for additional markup unless you want to do something special.

Comment: i see what you mean. i used them so i can fill the div with other content in the future if needed.

Comment: Maybe you fixed the issue already, because it lines up for me in IE9.

Comment: @Jonathan: It lines up at magnification 375% or above in IE9? Using IE8 again so pls let me know, I will install IE9 and check.

Comment: This works for me in IE 9... check your browser compatibility settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find a css reset being used on the site you provided.  It may just be a difference in how IE9 displays different elements (margins, padding etc).  I tried out the provided website in IE9 and didn't see the problem so it's a bit difficult to diagnose, though.

Comment: what do you mean by CSS reset? Did you grab a screenshot and compare it in Photoshop? It is 1 pixel out so overall the problem is not noticable from normal view. Thanks.

Comment: Each browser has certain default values for CSS settings on different elements. Unfortunately, these default values vary from browser to browser. In order to more likely get the same results in different browser, you use a "reset" file to set all those different default values to a consistent value.

Comment: Thanks phant0m! A CSS reset is very useful in many cases.  I see that it didn't quite fix your problem, though.  I tried to see it again and the problem only seems to show up around 375% or more zoom.  My guess is that it has something to do with a percent calculation "behind the scenes" in IE9's code.  I say this because using percents can often result in a decimal number which is typically just cut off (2.95 may become 2).  The pixel coordinates on a screen cannot be represented by a decimal value so sometimes images may be one pixel to the left or right of where you might expect.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should try to reset the css so that all browsers start out with the same defaults (like padding, margin ect.)

You can find a css-reset and more information here: http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

Edit:
Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/116754/best-css-reset

Comment: i tried the reset in the link provided but the situation did not change. i just copied and pasted the reset data at the top of the CSS file but maybe i need to do somehting else also? the funny thing is it renders perfectly in IE8 so i am confused why IE9 is causing problems. it leads me to believe that MS has changed something and thats why it is rendering differently.

Comment: did you try the ie8 compatibility mode?

Answer (score 1):

This line is in flash.

Change `body` background to white, and `.musicContainer` to `red`. You will see that html is not failing. In my opinion it is a flash like bug.

Try zooming in FF ( I tested in 5.0) on few zooms there is also same gap.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this approach for my websites I created prior to IE9.

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE8" />
```

Let it be the very first meta tag in your head tag, and IE9 will act as it was IE8, hopefully in the same identical way.

It solved all my problems in all my websites until now.

Enjoy

Comment: oh gosh no. Please! When IE9 came along it was such a relief to get a version of IE that is half decent... why are you crippling it by forcing it into busted-IE8-compatibility-mode??? It's like buying a Ferarri but replacing the engine with one from a Volkswagen because the spare parts are cheaper.

Comment: Cause almost all my websites are now incompatible, both for CSS and jQuery plugins which IE renders incorrectly... blame IE, not me. I simply cannot go back to all my websites and try to fix what's wrong one by one, just because IE 9 refuses to work correctly. With this, everything works ok, then for new websites I will of course render them fully compatible with IE also. So I don't see what this should be so wrong...

Comment: fair enough for specific cases, but I certainly wouldn't recommend this approach for general use unless all other options have been exhausted. But if your site works in IE8 but not IE9, how does it look in other browsers? IE9 is much better at following standards than IE8, so if IE9 breaks your site, the odds are it'll break in other browsers too.

Comment: They work perfectly in all the major browsers out there... sadly IE9 is far from being a good browser already. I would like to repeat what I've said in my answer above: this is the approach I'm using for websites created before IE9 was out. No need for this if you test your websites development in advance on IE9 too.

Answer (score 0):

It's related to flash redrawing. It behaves the same in ie8. Try resizing the browser window width and you will see that it doesn't update correctly.

Why dont you try a html5 player like http://www.jplayer.org/ instead?

Answer (score -1):

Maybe try using js to check the browser and alter the size or position with js in an if statement.

w3 schools has a nice tutorial on browser checking.

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_browser.asp

Comment: @iGuygar "any ways round this issue?" sounds like it to me

Comment: is this a IE9 bug? sorry i meant to take the other part out. :)

Comment: Guys please don't use w3schools site as an authoritative source. Please. I mean PLEASE. NO! Why? Here is why http://w3fools.com/

Comment: And this is BAD tutorial for browser checking. Seriously. Read https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Browser_Detection_and_Cross_Browser_Support instead.